# Linq multiple where with sorted order

Tags: c#, linq

I want to search a result set with linq for a word in two different fields, if the phrase is in "Title" then I want those results first and then if the phrase is in "Synopsis" I want those after title results.

I understand how .Where() and .orderby() + thenBy() works but how do you connect them together so the order is dependent on the where()?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your types that are involved in the query, together with some input-data and expected results. In particular show what you´ve tried and any possible errors you may get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply order by a value depending on which property contains the phrase:

```
var orderedResult = result.Where(x => x.Title == phrase || x.Synopsis == phrase)
                          .OrderBy(x => x.Title == phrase ? 1 : 2);
```

---

If you want to apply more sort criteria you can use `ThenBy`:

```
var orderedResult = result.Where(x => x.Title == phrase || x.Synopsis == phrase)
                          .OrderBy(x => x.Title == phrase ? 1 : 2)
                          .ThenBy(x => /* whatever you want to order by */);
```

Or if you want to order by another criteria first and apply the "phrase"-order only after that:

```
var orderedResult = result.Where(x => x.Title == phrase || x.Synopsis == phrase)
                          .OrderBy(x => /* whatever you want to order by */);
                          .ThenBy(x => x.Title == phrase ? 1 : 2)
```

Comment: So is above putting 1 or 2 into the order by then ordering by that?

Comment: @Cerls Yes, that's what `OrderBy` is for. It sorts the elements by the values the lambda returns for each element.